# What is the best practice for writing XHTML?

Tags: xhtml

Does anyone have a check list on the best practices for XHTML?

Comment: The best practice is to keep doing it until you're good at it.

Comment: Practice is no good without feedback to tell you when you get it wrong. It just makes people comfortable with their errors.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at **[XHTML Best Practices](http://www.graphicrating.com/2008/11/29/xhtml-best-practices/)**.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [W3C validator service](http://validator.w3.org/), you'll learn a lot about how your XHTML should be structured.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure the benefits outweigh [the pain](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#compatGuidelines) (otherwise stick to HTML)
2. [Validate](http://validator.w3.org/)
3. Separate [style](http://www.w3.org/Style/) from content
4. Be [accessible](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/)
5. Be [progressive](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)
6. Separate your concerns (keep CSS and JS in external files)
7. [Use UTF-8](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding) (unless you are working in a language where 16 or 32 is more efficient)
8. Test in multiple browsers as you develop (fixing all the IE6 bugs at the end is harder then fixing them as they show up)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say best practices are to make your code clean. Organize your tags.  Put notes if you want in your code /*This is a note*/.  Have an external style sheet. 
Like may already point out, validate often at http://validator.w3.org/
validate your CSS too at: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Also, don't overlook the

```
<meta name="Description" content="you put in here the description of your page.  It will appear on search engines" />
```

Give a specific title to each page.